# How Do I Use Channel Entry Data to Create a Dynamic Recipient List in Freeform?

Tags: emails, plugin-freeform, solspace

I'm trying to use the Solspace Freeform plugin for Craft CMS to create an email form. My form needs to have dynamic recipients, but I have a channel in the system that has the email addresses I need in it already.I'm not sure how to set up the template to use those email addresses in the dropdown field since the dynamic recipients field isn't supposed to have the actual email addresses in it. I've looked at the docs, but I'm not clear on how to set this up. Can anyone help me sort this out?

Comment: Is creating a custom template an option for you or do you refuse that method?

Comment: @RobinSchambach I am using a custom template that basically outputs custom html based on the layout set up in the composer. I got some advice from someone on Slack that suggested to set the values in the dynamic recipients form to the entry ids, then create a light plugin to grab the id and retrieve the email address from the entry. I'm working on the plugin now, though I'm a bit out of my depth. If you have any advice I'm definitely open to suggestions.

Comment: Do you need to hide the email addresses or why  do you make such a huge work around? It would be easier and faster to input them in the dropdown directly. Otherwise the craft docs is a good place to learn about plugins and pluginfactory.io will create your plugin.